# Why is Flow failing on a field that isn't even defined?

Tags: flow

I deleted a field on the Order object called Renewal_ACV__c and renamed another field to the same API name (I know not a great idea but...) - Now the Flow I have which generates an order from the Opportunity fails with the following error: An error occurred at element Create_Order (FlowRecordCreate).
INSERT --- INSERT FAILED --- ERRORS : (REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING) Required fields are missing: [Renewal_ACV__c],

I don't see Renewal_ACV__c defined anywhere in the Flow, so why is it failing and how can I fix this?

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the field "`Renewal_ACV__c`" on order object is a mandatory field for an order to be created. So make sure you have a value for the field.

Comment: Thanks Anurag!  - that was the problem.  I forgot that I had made that field mandatory last night.

Comment: Please mark if your problem is solved for the community.

Comment: dumb question... how/where do I Mark the problem as "Solved"?